# How to debug python source code using GDB in Cygwin for Windows 10 (x64)

Tags: python, debugging, gdb, cygwin, gdb-python

I usually code in python and I need a debugger. I chose GDB as it also helps in debugging my c++ applications. i have read the python documentation on GDB debugger but it isn't clear to me still. i had cygwin installed and with it i have also installed GDB on windows 10 (x64) . Do i still need to install somethong more?
And after installing it what should be my next steps to run the debugger with breakpoints and all other regular features (without creating an extra file, as I read in some answers)

Comment: I have not actually used gdb for debugging Python. I know you can do it and it is specially useful if you want to debug python extensions. But if you want to debug just "regular" Python code a Python debugger is probably better (enough and easier to use). One nice debugger for python is pudb (it's not a typo for pdb, it is really pudb). You can install it using pip, but I have only used in Linux.

Comment: PDB is the builtin module for debugging python code. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

Comment: @darcamo There is no option of pudb in the list of packages to download.

Comment: if it works like a separate program only, such programs can always be used but i need that can directly be used in cygwin like softwares